# Google Cloud Endpoints (using GAE Java, Eclipse) - Which methods from class are included?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I cannot find an answer in the Google docs. As I understand from the docs, the @Api annotation is applied to a class to indicate that it is part of the Endpoint API and the @ApiMethod then indicates which methods of that class is part of the Cloud API.

However, even if a method is not annotated with @ApiMethod the Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints Builder still includes that method as part of the Cloud API.

How can I exclude a method from the API? If it is not possible, is a good alternative then to pass the received API parameters to a separate object (which is a field of the annotated class) that do contain the required method?

I include the following code which is a class annotated with @Api for clarification (see comment on top of ggetStr method):

```
package com.barcodeapp.www.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;

@Api(
    name = "cetest",
    version = "v1",
    scopes = {EndpointsConstants.EMAIL_SCOPE},
    clientIds = {EndpointsConstants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, EndpointsConstants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
    audiences = {EndpointsConstants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE}
)
public class CloudTest  {

   public List<String> list() {
        List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
        strs.add("a"); strs.add("b");
        return strs;
   }

   /* THE FOLLOWING METHOD NEEDS TO BE EXCLUDED FROM CLOUD API */
   public String ggetStr() {
       return "abc";
   }

}
```

EDIT: I have included the library .jar file in the WAR/WEB-INF/lib folder - no difference.

Below is the two classes for completeness:

```
package com.cloudtest.lib;

public class ClassInLibProj {

}
```

and

```
package com.cloudtest.my;

public class ClassInLocalProj {

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it seems that the only way currently for your method not to be included is to make that `private` in your class.

This is because:

- If your method is annotated with `APIMethod`, then it is included
- If you method is not annotated with `APIMethod` but it is public, it is taken too. This is likely because of the `API` annotation at the top.

There is an issue raised : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10372&thanks=10372&ts=1386300958